# update values in df after groupby AND get_group

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, merge, transform

I have a data frame with of the form

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dim_unit' :['m', 'cm', 'cm', 'm', 'ft', 'in'], 'Length' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'Width' : [5,6,7,8,9,10] })
```

I am trying to use groupby to group by the different dimensional unit, and then taking the sub-dataframe, apply a scale factor to each of 'Length' and 'Width' columns so the resulting data frame is in the same dimensions. (The actual one has more units, and columns to transpose).

The following works, except that I cannot get it to update it in original data frame (obviously repeating again for "Height" and "m" etc).

```
g= df.groupby('dim_unit')

g.get_group('cm')[["Width"]].apply( lambda x: x*100)
```

I have tried using transform instead of apply but that did not appear to change anything. I have also tried

```
df['len_cm_to_m']= df.get_group('cm')[["Width"]].apply( lambda x: x*100)
```

But this result in a column with lots of Nan, and then I would have to repeat for each of cm, in, ft, etc and merge the values together into one column of transformed units.
In particular, because there are about 5 different types of units which I am grouping by, and each of the apply functions will differ for each unit, and then multiple columns that I am working across, this would create 15 new columns for my whole dataset with lots of Nan values, which I would then need to merge and that just seems like a mess.

So, is there a way to update the values in df from the resulting apply function? Ideally it would be an update of the values. Or I was also thinking of trying to use a merge (or similar) to update the column by matching the indices?

Any advice on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite existing records? Append new ones?

Comment: Overwrite existing. Though if it resulted in a SINGLE new column for each length and height, that would be ok. The problem I have with a new column is that I have to create one for the height (or length) of each 'm', 'cm', 'in' etc.

Comment: Note that `.groupby` in the 2nd code snippet doesn't actually do anything. Calling `.groupby` on a data frame does not perform an in-place operation on the data. It makes a new grouped data frame, which you discard by not assigning to any variable. If you try to run the code as-written, you get an error: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'get_group'`.

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my question, I understand that it makes a new data frame. I am wondering how I can extract that to update the original, especially when I am applying different operations to different groups.

Comment: I haven't said anything about assigning the result yet.. it's just that the code you posted doesn't even work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to groupby, you can just `map` the unit to the scale, then multiply:

```
# convert all the units to cm
conversion_dict = {
    "m": 100,
    "cm": 1,
    "ft": 12 * 2.54,
    "in": 2.54
}

df[['Length','Width']] = df[['Length','Width']].mul(df['dim_unit'].map(conversion_dict), axis=0)
```

Output:

```
  dim_unit  Length   Width
0        m  100.00  500.00
1       cm    2.00    6.00
2       cm    3.00    7.00
3        m  400.00  800.00
4       ft  152.40  274.32
5       in   15.24   25.40
```

**Note**: It may be better/clearer to have new columns instead:

```
df[['Length_cm','Width_cm']] = df[['Length','Width']].mul(df['dim_unit'].map(conversion_dict), axis=0)
```

And you'd have:

```
  dim_unit  Length  Width  Length_cm  Width_cm
0        m       1      5     100.00    500.00
1       cm       2      6       2.00      6.00
2       cm       3      7       3.00      7.00
3        m       4      8     400.00    800.00
4       ft       5      9     152.40    274.32
5       in       6     10      15.24     25.40
```

Comment: Thank you, that does what I want. The only issue is that it is throwing the following warning: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead  See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy"

Comment: @Elise at some point, your `df` was constructed by slicing/selecting rows from a larger data frame. For efficiency, Pandas does not copy the data when you do that. That's what the warning is saying: you are doing this thing that you probably didn't mean to do.